# Getting a wierd 'InvalidCastException' in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, collections

I am getting the following exception in C#:

> InvalidCastException: Could not convert from type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProj.Data.Entities.Student]' to
>   type 'MyProj.Data.Access.IStudent'.

My project compiles successfully. I have two objects defined as follows:

```
public interface IStudent
{
    long ID { get; set; }
    string SystemCode { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } 
}
public class Student : IStudent
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string SystemCode { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } 
}

public interface ICourseRequest
{
    long ID { get; set; }
    long StudentID { get; set; }
    int CourseID { get; set; }
    int? FacultyID { get; set; }
    DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    IStudent Student { get; set; }
}

public class CourseRequest : ICourseRequest
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long StudentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int? FacultyID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public IStudent Student { get; set; }
}
```

I am using SQLtoLinq to retrieve my data (from SQL Server) as follows:

```
IList<ICourseRequest> result = _database.course_requests.Select(a => new CourseRequest
{        
    CreationDate = a.crsreq_create_date,
    StartDate = a.crsreq_start,
    FacultyID = a.crsreq_faculty,
    ID = a.crsreq_id,
    CourseID = a.crsreq_crs,
    StudentID = a.crsreq_student,
    Student =  _database.students.Where(p => p.stud_id == a.crsreq_student)
                                 .Select(s => new Student
                                  {
                                      ID = p.stud_id,
                                      DateOfBirth = s.stud_dob,
                                      FirstName = s.stud_fname,
                                      LastName = s.stud_lname,
                                      SystemCode = s.stud_sys_code
                                  }).SingleOrDefault(),
}).ToList<ICourseRequest>();
```

Why is this cast exception thrown at runtime while the project compiles successfully?

Comment: What line is it on? Are you *sure* it's from that snippet of code?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: you're trying to cast `List<Student>` to interface `IStudent`, which was invalid. In what condition the error appeared?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto But I have a SingleOrDefault() at the end of that nested select

Comment: @Rob The error is at the query

Comment: @progrAmmar, can you try adding a `ToList()` call before the `SingleOrDefault()`. I'm curious as to whether it has to do with the way the queries gets executed that is causing the cast exception.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how I fixed that :|.... Check out the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very wierd. I have been querying like this throughout the project (with other objects) and only this gave an error.

I fixed it by casting it as `IStudent`. I don't know why the simple `SingleOrDefault` did not work. Can anyone explain why?

This is what fixed it:

```
IList<ICourseRequest> result = _database.course_requests.Select(a => new CourseRequest
{        
    CreationDate = a.crsreq_create_date,
    StartDate = a.crsreq_start,
    FacultyID = a.crsreq_faculty,
    ID = a.crsreq_id,
    CourseID = a.crsreq_crs,
    StudentID = a.crsreq_student,
    Student =  _database.students.Where(p => p.stud_id == a.crsreq_student)
                                 .Select(s => new Student
                                  {
                                      ID = p.stud_id,
                                      DateOfBirth = s.stud_dob,
                                      FirstName = s.stud_fname,
                                      LastName = s.stud_lname,
                                      SystemCode = s.stud_sys_code
                                  }).SingleOrDefault() as IStudent, //<-- This is what fixed it
}).ToList<ICourseRequest>();
```

Comment: Might be hiding the error and setting `Student` to null. What happens if you explicitly cast it? `Student = (IStudent)_database.students...`?

Comment: Can you try changing to `SingleOrDefault<IStudent>()`? Seeing this answer I believe that LinqToSql didn't know how to covert the result of `Student` to the base type.

Comment: @Adrian the error prevails if I do SIngleOrDefault<IStudent> for some reason LinqToSql thinks I am querying a List!. When there's a SingleOrDefault in the end.

Comment: @progrAmmar thanks for the enlightenment. It must be just a quirk of the LinqToSql query engine when you use interfaces. I am assuming that if the property the result was being assigned to was `Student` instead of `IStudent` the problem would also go away.

Comment: @Adrian but the thing is, I have many other Objects (and list of those objects) I am using the same method of querying (without casting) and they work for some reason. Like I have an `Examination` Class Where I have interfaces which I can query without casting :-S